# GAE - Datastore model class with function that put()s itself in the database?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to write a Datastore model class which has a function which creates the object and adds it to the Datastore all at once. This is what I currently have (which doesn't work):

```
class Channel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    subscriber_list = db.ListProperty(users.User)

    def addChannelWithName(name):
        channel = Channel()
        channel.name = name
        channel.put()
```

From this I'm getting the problem that the first thing passed to the addChannelWithName() is suppose to be a Channel instance, but of course with what I'm trying to do a channel instance shouldn't exist yet. It should be created during this function. How should I go about making this work? Is there a way to keep this function as a method of Channel or should this be a function completely separate from the class? Or should I be doing something else? Thank you much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could make it a class method or static method.  That way if your using the model somewhere else you don't need to import the seperate function from the module.

```
class Channel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    subscriber_list = db.ListProperty(users.User)

    @classmethod
    def addChannelWithName(cls,name):
        channel = cls()
        channel.name = name
        channel.put()
```

or a static method and omit cls.

You would call it as Channel.addChannelWithName(name)
If you use a class or static method I would drop the "Channel" bit from the method name as it's redundant.   ie Channel.addWithName(name) because you only call it from the class.

Comment: def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
      super(Channel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Be careful you normally do not have an ____init____ method on model classes, unless you know what you are doing. db.Model heavily uses metaclasses.  If you look around SO you will see this is a common question and you are normally warned off it.   e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913775/db-model-class-variables-and-init

Comment: I have used it to check uniqueness on a field, wasn't aware it might be problematic

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to make it a top-level, standalone function instead of a method. (You could make it a staticmethod, or -- with a change to the call signature -- a classmethod, but I don't really see any advantage to doing that here.)